# In Constraint Layout Is it possible to put 4 TextViews in a Horizental chain with different space between each views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In `ConstraintLayout`, is it possible to put 4 `TextView`s in a horizontal chain with different spaces between each view?

For example, like the below picture and I want in different screen-sizes TextView's position to be the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of an alternative solution without using a chain. You can use `Guideline` to achieve the layout that you are trying to design. I have created one for you. Let me know if that helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_right_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".9" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_left_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_top_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_top_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Text 3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_top_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 4"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_top_margin" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here how it looks in the portrait mode.

[image: portrait]

And this is how it looks in the landscape mode.

[image: landscape]